# Python IDEs stopped working

Tags: python, ide

I'm a beginner programming student, and was using PyScriptor as my Python IDE. Today I wanted to start working and surprisingly, I get an error when starting PyScriptor:

> Python could not be properly initialized. We must quit.

I downloaded other IDEs to test if it was just PyScriptor, but no.

Sublime Text 2: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=343C352B8B8B2009!2382&authkey=!AATFdAsgS37dLxQ&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

Geany: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=343C352B8B8B2009!2383&authkey=!ADNKPLz3bw7zhn8&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

What is causing the problem?

I was on the verge of installing Windows 10 anyways, so I clean installed the new OS thinking that it might fix it, but I'm getting the same errors as with Windows 8.1.

I didn't uninstall Python (I had both 2 and 3 on Windows 8.1) and did nothing that might cause this kind of behavior. Again, the errors were the same before I installed Windows 10, so it's not Windows 10 problem. I installed latest Python 2.9 on the current OS and restarted, and it still shows up the same errors.